# Why won't SQL accept one attribute, but it accepts the others?

Tags: java, html, sql

Right, I have a SQL table called "Person" with the following attributes

```
"SV_NR" 
"VORNAME"
"NACHNAME"
"POSTLEITZAHL" 
"ORT"
"STRASSE"
"HAUSNUMMER"
```

(it's german, don't worry about it)

Now I'm making a .jsp, that's supposed to make a new entry in this table. Looks like this:

```
> <form method="post" action="person_anlegen.jsp" style="display:
> inline-block">    <input type="hidden" name="menu"
> value="person_anlegen" />         <table class="table table-striped">
>       <tbody>
>           <tr><td>SVNr.</td><td><input name="svnr" value="${param.svnr}" /></td></tr>
>           <tr><td>Vorname</td><td><input name="vorname" value="${param.vorname}" /></td></tr>
>           <tr><td>Nachname</td><td><input name="nachname" value="${param.nachname}" /></td></tr>
>           <tr><td>Postleitzahl</td><td><input name="postleitzahl" value="${param.plz}" /></td></tr>
>           <tr><td>Ort</td><td><input name="ort" value="${param.ort}" /></td></tr>
>           <tr><td>Strasse</td><td><input name="strasse" value="${param.strasse}" /></td></tr>
>           <tr><td>Hausnummer</td><td><input name="hausnummer" value="${param.hausnummer}" /></td></tr>        </tbody>    </table>    <button
> type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right">
>                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Anlegen
>               </button> </form>
> 
> <br />  
> 
> <c:choose>    <c:when test="${empty param.svnr}">         <div
> class="warning">
>         <p >Bitte geben Sie zumindest eine SV-Nr. ein.</p>
>      </div>   </c:when>   <c:otherwise>       <sql:query var="p_anlage"           sql="           INSERT INTO person          (           SV_NR, VORNAME, NACHNAME,
> STRASSE, HAUSNUMMER, ORT, POSTLEITZAHL            )           VALUES          (
>           ${param.svnr}, ${param.vorname}, ${param.nachname},
> ${param.strasse}, ${param.hausnummer}, ${param.plz}, ${param.ort} 
>           );          "       />      </c:otherwise> </c:choose>
```

`

When I fill out my form and press the button, I get this:

```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:           INSERT INTO person          (           SV_NR,
> VORNAME, NACHNAME, STRASSE, HAUSNUMMER, ORT, POSTLEITZAHL             )
>           VALUES          (           4589654812, Georg, Schramm, Schillerstraße, 12, ,
> Bad Homburg vor der Höhe              );          : ORA-00936: missing expression
> 
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:592)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:400)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:344)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

See? Between "Schillerstraße, 12" and "Bad Homburg vor ..." there is an expression missing - POSTLEITZAHL (= param.plz).

Why?? I used the exact same syntax as for all the others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong on so many levels that I barely know where to start.

---

**First** (this is why your input value is not placed into the SQL statement):

`${param.plz}` is not replaced because your form doesn't contain a `plz` input field - you named the input field `postleitzahl`:

```
<input name="postleitzahl" value="${param.plz}" />
```

Correspondingly, in your SQL statement you need to reference the `param.postleitzahl` parameter.

---

**Second** (this is why changing the order of the last two values gives you an error "ORA-00917: missing comma")

You place your input values directly into the SQL statement. This works for numbers but not for strings - literal strings in SQL have to be placed in single quotes (long sql attribute wrapped around for legibility):

```
<sql:query var="p_anlage" 
  sql="INSERT INTO person (SV_NR, VORNAME, NACHNAME, STRASSE, HAUSNUMMER, ORT, POSTLEITZAHL) 
       VALUES ('${param.svnr}', '${param.vorname}', '${param.nachname}', '${param.strasse}', 
               '${param.hausnummer}', '${param.ort}', '${param.postleitzahl}' );"/>
```

---

**Third**: creating SQL statements from user input should never be done - this almost always leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities in your application.

With the statement above, if someone would enter `"A', '1'); delete from person; --"` as value for "ort" he would be able to delete all records from the person table.

Instead you should use a prepared statement with param tags:

```
<sql:query var="p_anlage" 
    sql="INSERT INTO person (SV_NR, VORNAME, NACHNAME, STRASSE, HAUSNUMMER, ORT, POSTLEITZAHL) 
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? );">
  <sql:param value="${param.svnr}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.vorname}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.nachname}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.strasse}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.hausnummer}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.ort}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.postleitzahl}"/>
</sql:query>
```

---

**Fourth**: you are using the `<sql:query />` tag. This tag is intended for SQL statements that return result sets (primarily SELECT statements).

For INSERT and UPDATE statements, you should use the `<sql:update />` tag:

```
<sql:update var="p_anlage" 
    sql="INSERT INTO person (SV_NR, VORNAME, NACHNAME, STRASSE, HAUSNUMMER, ORT, POSTLEITZAHL) 
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? );">
  <sql:param value="${param.svnr}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.vorname}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.nachname}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.strasse}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.hausnummer}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.ort}"/>
  <sql:param value="${param.postleitzahl}"/>
</sql:update>
```

---

Useful references to the documentation:

- [Java EE tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html)
- [Tutorialspoint JSP Database Access](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much. I know it's bad, but I'm working with 2 unfamiliar languages here and I'm running out of time. It's only for demonstration, no real user will ever touch it. So anything that runs is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the last two values is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work. Now I get ORA-00917: missing comma